# Jasperreports four sets of multiple dynamic images

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports, ireport

i have a window which have four sections of multiples images... i need to export those images `the 4 sections` into a `JasperReport` using `Ireport tool` i was wondering if this is possible i never try this situation. this is what i need.

1). set the 4 sections with images separately with any number of pics.

i already know how to pass the images to the report to renderize.

Questions .

1). main question is how to strech the component what component i should use?

2). what is the version of `JasperReports and Ireport` i need to have this feature.

3). how can i pass multiple dynamic images from `JAVA` to `Ireport`

any help resource or trick is hugely appreciate..

**UPDATE**

i would like to export this to PDF `i havent try nothing so far` and i would like to in every section pass the `N` image and the ireport with put each one side by side and the component strech vertically to be able to fill all the images per section..

**Image is my current window with 2 sets of images... my ZK Page** as you can see there is multiples images per section.

[image]
this what i have try so far.. 
[image]

my questions are

1). how is not only 3 images but 10 or 12 dynamically from DB.

2). how can i pass the data from multiples images to `Ireport` how can `Ireport` handle it

something like

```
Band myBand = ..extractBandFromReport
for(Image image:listOfImages)
{
    image.setSize(100);
    image.setHeight(50);
    myBand.add(image);//adding dynamic images to the band..
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. For example, you can export report as *pdf* file. How it should work in *pdf* file, for example?